# Renaming a DLL's dependencies

Tags: windows, dll, dependencies, rename

Are there any tools or methods for renaming a DLL's dependencies?

I'm working with a large program that uses a significant number of third party dependencies. I'm able to compile nearly all of these dependencies into DLLs with a specific naming convention (i.e. libSomething_x86.dll). However, there is one dependency (FFmpeg) that I can't easily compile, but pre-compiled DLLs are available. So far, I've renamed the DLL files and recreated the import libraries to use the new names. My application compiles, but fails to run because FFmpeg is composed of multiple DLLs and they reference each other (with the original names). Since the new DLL names are longer than the original DLL names, I can't simply hex edit the DLL files. I can't use side-by-side redirection, manifest tricks, or "wrapper"/"dummy" DLLs because the fact the DLLs are pre-compiled and renamed must be completely transparent to the other application developers.

I was hoping to find a method of unlinking the DLL, editing the dependency list, and then relinking the DLL. Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: To the person who downvoted my question, can you please leave a comment describing your issues with the question? Thank you.